# Why does 'invoke-history' hang in powershell?

Tags: powershell

If my last command was something like 'dir', then invoke-history seems to work fine. If my last command was something like 'vim $profile', invoke-history will show the command and hang. Is there any way to fix this? A lot of my work in powershell involves editing a script and then running it... This is becoming a huge issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a ***bug* as of Windows PowerShell 5.1 / PowerShell [Core] 7.0**:

Programs such as `vim` rely on being able to print to the terminal (console) *directly*, without PowerShell as an intermediary.

- With *direct* invocation, this works as intended.
- With invocation via `Invoke-History`, PowerShell *does* appear to be insert itself between `vim` and the terminal, which makes `vim` malfunction:

  - Error `Invoke-History: Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal` is emitted.
  - The `vim` UI does *not* appear, even though `vim` is *running*, as evidenced by the fact that you can type `:q` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit.

The bug has been reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12307).

---

**Workarounds**:

You could roll your own [`Invoke-History`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-history) function to place in your `$PROFILE` file, which manually retrieves and executes a previous command from the history:

```
function Invoke-History {
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
  param(
    [string] $Id = (Get-History -Count 1).Id
  )
  $cmd = if ($Id -as [long]) {
      (Get-History -ErrorAction Stop -Id $Id).CommandLine
    } else {
      (Get-History).Where({ $_.CommandLine.TrimStart() -match ('^' + [regex]::Escape($Id)) }, 'Last').CommandLine
    }
  if (-not $cmd) { Throw "Cannot locate the history for command line $Id" }
  if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($cmd)) {
    # Note: Invoke-Expression is safe to use here, but
    #       should generally be avoided.
    Invoke-Expression $cmd
  }
}
```

Note: The built-in `r` and `ihy` aliases will automatically invoke the custom function rather than the cmdlet, because functions have higher command-lookup precedence than cmdlets.

---

Alternatively, use **other ways to execute commands from the history**:

- Use the *up-arrow key* to navigate backward in the command history (and *down-arrow* to navigate forward again).
- Type `#` and then one of the following:

  - *Immediately* type *part of a previous command* - do not add a space after `#` - and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through matching commands.

    - Unfortunately, you cannot recall *assignments* or *expressions* this way, such as `$foo = ...` or `21 *2`.
  - *Immediately* type the *number (`Id`)* of the command to re-execute, as shown by `Get-History`, and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to show that command.
  - Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit the command displayed.
- Use `PSReadLine`'s `ReverseSearchHistory` function, which is bound to key combination <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> by default:

  - Press the key combination and type part of a previous command: the most recent matching command will show automatically; press the key combination repeatedly to cycle through *all* matching commands.
  - Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit the command displayed or <kbd>Tab</kbd> to edit it first.

<sup>Tip of the hat to [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2674513/mike) for his help.</sup>

Note: As of PowerShell 7.2, only the `PSReadLine` method is based on the latter's persistent cross-session history; the `#` method only knows about commands from the current session.

---

Comment: Good points, @Mike - answer updated. Also see my note re only being able to recall _commands_, not also _assignments_  and _expressions_.